# Error checking for updates for either Gallery - VS2012 Update 1

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I've just updated my Visual Studio 2012 with Update 1. I wanted to check if there were any associated updates, so I jumped into Tools->Extensions and Updates and selected Updates. It was all good on the Product Updates entry but if I select either Visual Studio Gallery or Samples Gallery I am displayed

> Cannot check for updates because the following error(s) occurred while
>   trying to contact the server:
>
> The type initializer for
>   'System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility' threw an exception.
>
> Please click here to retry the request.

Retrying didn't do any good. I know I don't need to check as I have the automatic detection turned on but I wouldn't have seen the error if I didn't. What I'd like to know is whether anyone else is experiencing the same issue? It's happening on multiple Windows 7 machines here but not my Windows 8 machine.

Anyone having the same problem?